# How to replace character $ by using re.sub?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose we have the following string and list of numbers:

`my_string = "We change $ to 10, $ to 22, $ to 120, $ to 230 and $ to 1000."`

`nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

By only using `re.sub`, how to replace the `$` character in `my_string` with each of the elements in the list to have:

`"We change 1 to 10, 2 to 22, 3 to 120, 4 to 230 and 5 to 1000."`

When I use `re.sub(r'\b$', lambda i: str(nums.pop(0)), my_string)`, it doesn't work and the reason is that `$` is a reserved character in `re.sub` and according to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

> Matches the end of the string or just before the newline at the end of the string ...

So if I want to replace the character `$` with a constant value by using `re.sub`, is there any solution for it?

Comment: btw, the docs that you've linked include this: ``\$ matches the character '$'``

Comment: @MikeScotty Thanks I just found it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape the $ like this:

```
re.sub(r'\$', lambda i: str(nums.pop(0)), my_string)
```

Comment: You can also do an iteration to do the same thing: `for i in nums: my_string = re.sub(r'\$', str(i), my_string, count=1)`. I really like the lambda way though.

Comment: @HampusLarsson Thank you. But in terms of time complexity your suggestion is less efficient.